# How to extract specific file from partially downloaded tar file

Tags: gzip, ubuntu-18.04, tar

I have a large `tar` file but it could not be downloaded completely as the browser crashed when verifying the download. Is it possible to extract some files from this tar?

I am able to view the files using `tar -tf abc.tar` and this shows the directories and folders

```
a/
a/b/
a/b/1
a/b/2
```

However if I use `tar -xvf abc.tar a/b/1` it gives

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open abc.tar
```

Is there any way to only extract the available files in the `tar` in such a case?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `-z` option?

Comment: My bad, `-z` is for `gzip` and would be ignored in this case, have updated in edit.

Comment: Please add output of `file abc.tar` to your question.

Comment: `file` gives output as `abc.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)`

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. `tar -xvf abc.tar a/b/1` gave `x a/b/1` and extracted the file into those directories, also creating the directories.

Comment: @MarkAdler I was able to extract some files using `tar -xvf` but not all of them (I guess this is because the `tar` file did not download completely to the folder). Can I use the command in such a way to extract all those files that can be ?

Comment: tar already extracts all of the files it can from a partial tar file. On the last partial entry, it will say "Truncated tar archive".

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer is "**it can't be done**". The answer stands behind the `zip` algorithm and how the saved file is structured. Some detailed explanations you can find here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format) but I will extract and present you the most important ones:

> A ZIP file is correctly identified by the presence of an end of
> central directory record which is located at the end of the archive
> structure in order to allow the easy appending of new files. If the
> end of central directory record indicates a non-empty archive, the
> name of each file or directory within the archive should be specified
> in a central directory entry, along with other metadata about the
> entry, and an offset into the ZIP file, pointing to the actual entry
> data. This allows a file listing of the archive to be performed
> relatively quickly, as the entire archive does not have to be read to
> see the list of files. The entries within the ZIP file also include
> this information, for redundancy, in a local file header. Because ZIP
> files may be appended to, only files specified in the central
> directory at the end of the file are valid. Scanning a ZIP file for
> local file headers is invalid (except in the case of corrupted
> archives), as the central directory may declare that some files have
> been deleted and other files have been updated.

So if you don't have the `end` of the file downloaded you can't read any of it. I will post again the most important sentence to make things clear:

> "A ZIP file is correctly identified by the presence of an end of
> central directory record which is located at the end of the archive
> structure in order to allow the easy appending of new files. "

Comment: As it turns out, it is only a .tar file.

Comment: Your answer is both irrelevant to the question and is incorrect. The question is about tar files, not zip files. Also zip files can be [read and decompressed sequentially](https://github.com/madler/sunzip).

Comment: Mmmm.... you are right. The "gzip" tag from the question made me think that the "tar" package is compressed with "zip" algorithm and that is why I gave this answer... So there are high chances that this may be a reason why a file can not be extracted from it.